# Keeping a dynamic-dimensioned square centered in a rectangle

Tags: geometry, puzzle

For some reason this problem which seemed fairly easy on the surface has given me a lot of trouble. I have a square who's side length changes based on an independent variable. The square's upper left corner is at the origin, and the square's lower right corner is at $(l_f,-l_f)$, where $l_f$ is the length of the square.

Our rectangle must always have a width to heigth ratio of $1280/720$. When the square is at it's initial length, the length of the square and the height of the rectangle should  be the same. Additionally, the square must always be directly in the middle of the rectangle (that is, the center of the square and the center of the rectangle coincide). And finally, the ratio of the square's length and the rectangles lengths must get linearly smaller as the square's length decreases, and linearly larger as the square's length increases. I need the equations for $(x_i,y_i)$ and $(x_f,y_f)$, where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the coordinates of the top left corner of the rectangle, and $x_f,y_f$ are the coordinates of the bottom right corner of the rectangle,  based on the following variables.

$d = $ an independent variable, in the domain $(0, \infty)$, initial value of $1$

$l_i = $ constant (initial size of square...for my problem it is 250)

$l_f = l_i\cdot d \rightarrow$ (where $l_f$ is the length of the square)

**My Attempt**

I believe my attempt at getting the y limits is correct. 
$$y_i = \frac{l_f}{2} - \frac{l_i}{2}$$ $$y_f = \frac{l_f}{2} + \frac{l_i}{2}$$

The $x$ coordinates are the hard ones now. Because the initial height of the rectangle and the length of the square must be the same, we need a corrective term to add onto the $x$ coordinates. The following term worked (not sure if it's neccessary in the end though). $\frac{1}{2} \cdot l_f(\frac{1280}{720} - 1)$. Then, if the independent variable changes from it's default value of 1, we need another term since the width and height of the rectangle can't continue to scale at the same rate, otherwise the 1280x720 ratio is not maintained. I thought this term would do the trick $\frac{1280}{720}(\frac{l_f}{2} - \frac{l_i}{2})$, but using these terms does not give me the correct answer. Using these terms, I get the following:

$$x_i = \left(1 + \frac{1280}{720}\right) \left(\frac{l_f}{2} - \frac{l_i}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{2} \cdot l_f\left(\frac{1280}{720} - 1\right)$$
$$x_f = \left(\frac{l_f}{2} + \frac{l_i}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{2} \cdot l_f\left(\frac{1280}{720} - 1\right) - \frac{1280}{720} \left(\frac{l_f}{2} - \frac{l_i}{2}\right)$$

Like I said this doesn't work though. Let me know if you have any tips, thanks!

Comment: Should the rectangle shrink to have the height of the square? What are $x_i$, $y_i$, $x_f$ and $y_f$?

Comment: Just made an edit to that =p, to add to what I edited, the rectangle should look "much larger" in comparison to the square as the square's length decreases and vice-versa. The progression should be linear.

Comment: The edit doesn't answer any of my questions though.

Comment: Sorry, see my above comment. My post should now contain all neccessary info

Comment: I still don't understand how the rectangle is supposed to scale. Should it have the height of the square? If not, what determines its height? Maybe you could describe what the actual problem is you are working on.

Comment: For a more complete description of the problem, look under the physics section here...nobody seems to want to help there though lol http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75414/keeping-a-constant-resolution-scale-of-an-image

Comment: If the square has corners $(0,0)$ and $(l_f, -l_f)$, should the rectangle also has its top edge at $y=0$ and its bottom edge at $y=-l_f$?

Comment: Yes, but only initially, when $d$ = 1. If you look at Adriano's solution (or mine) for the $y$ dimension, it is correct. This means that as $d$ gets larger and larger, the rectangle's y dimensions *linearly* get bigger and bigger than the square's length. I don't know to be more clear than that, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding everything correctly, here's what I think you're looking for:
\begin{align*}
y_i &= \dfrac{-l_i}{2} - \dfrac{l_f}{2} \\
y_f &= \dfrac{-l_i}{2} + \dfrac{l_f}{2} \\
x_i &= \dfrac{l_i}{2} - \dfrac{\frac{1280}{720}l_f}{2} \\
x_f &= \dfrac{l_i}{2} + \dfrac{\frac{1280}{720}l_f}{2} \\
\end{align*}
Here's what I did. Initially, the centre of the square/rectangle is at $(l_i/2, -l_i/2)$. Note that linearly scaling the square/rectangle by a factor of $d$ will not change this centre point. Now to get the corners, we simply have to either add or subtract half the dimensions of the rectangle. Initially, the rectangle has a height of $l_i$, so scaling it by $d$ gives us a new height of $l_f$. Since we know the aspect ratio, it follows that the new width must be $\frac{1280}{720}l_f$.

Comment: "Note that linearly scaling the square/rectangle by a factor of d  will not change this centre point"....remember the origin is not at the center point, it's at the upper left hand corner of the square, so it indeed changes the location of the center point

Comment: Also I initially tried what you are doing, but because the square's origin is not at the center, using these formulas actually does not keep the square's center and the rectangle's center aligned.

Answer (score -1):

From the answers you gave to my comments, I figured you mixed up the $y$-direction in your question. You say that the rectangle is centered at $(l_f/2, -l_f/2)$, but in your calculation you use $(l_f/2, l_f/2)$ to obtain the $y$-boundaries of your rectangle. (Note that you get $y_f=l_f$ for $d=1$ instead of $y_f=-l_f$ as you told me in a comment.)

Suppose the formulas for the $y$-boundaries are correct in your question and the center of the square is in fact at $(l_f/2, l_f/2)$ so everything fits together, I would guess you want the following $x$-boundaries for the rectangle:

$$\begin{align*}
x_i &= \frac{l_f}2 - \frac{1280}{720} \cdot \frac{l_i}{2} \\
x_f &= \frac{l_f}2 + \frac{1280}{720} \cdot \frac{l_i}{2}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: This doesn't preserve the ratio of $x$ limits to $y$ limits...=(

Comment: as the scale increases, the y limits outgrow the x limits pretty quickly, which should never happen

Comment: I think it does, from your formulas we have $y_f-y_i=l_i$, from my formulas we have $x_f-x_i=\frac{1280}{720} l_i$, so the ratio is correct.

Comment: I have the code running right in front of me. Both the code and just looking at your solutions tells me it doesn't work...

Comment: Once again, this would work if the origin was at the center of the square, but in fact it's at the upper left hand corner. Remember the size of the square changes as $d$ changes

Comment: I just explained why it is correct from the way you explained your problem. Explain properly why this is still wrong. I described a rectangle with center at $(l_f/2, l_f/2)$, the same height you gave and the correct aspect ratio. Why is this wrong?

Comment: It clearly doesn't maintain the correct aspect ratio for x and y....can you really not see it? As $d$ increases, only $l_f$ changes, which means according to your equations, both $x$ and $y$ are changing at the same rate. That just cannot possibly maintain the aspect ratio of 1280x720 for $x$ and $y$...does that help?

Comment: Yes it can. From what you wrote in your question, the height of the rectangle is fixed ($l_i$), thus the width is also fixed ($1280/720 \cdot l_i$), only the position changes, by changing all coordinates at the same rate. If this is not what you want, the $y$-boundaries you proposed are already wrong.

Comment: Consider the simple case when $\frac{l_f}{2} = \frac{1280}{720}\cdot\frac{l_i}{2}$. Then $x_i = 0$ and $x_f = \frac{1280}{720}\cdot l_f$. Now the square's left edge will be aligned with the left edge of the rectangle. This makes it impossible to be centered.

Comment: No, $x_f=\frac{1280}{720}\cdot l_i=l_f$ in that case. Both edges will be aligned and the centers do coincide.

Comment: sorry made a typo for $x_f$ but what do you have to say about $x_i = 0$ where the left edge of the square and the rectangular are aligned? I'm not seeing how both this is possible and their centers are aligned simultaneously. At least my code is supporting what I'm saying

Comment: This is perhaps turning into a long drawn out argument, I may go ahead and close this question and we could continue via private message